# Strange output with Python Lists

Tags: python-2.7, list

I have a dataframe: Outlet_results 
it goes something like this

```
index  Calendar year/Week     Material    Sellthru Qty
0           37.2013            ABC          2
1           38.2913            ABC          7
2           37.2913            BCG          22
3           39.2013            XYZ          5
```

Now, I wanted a separate list for the Materials and week for further coding.

I used this code for the material list

```
mat_outlet = list(set(outlet_result['Material']))
```

It works perfectly and gives me 3 values (ABC, BCG, XYZ)

However, the week list shows a faulty output even though the code is same.

```
week_outlet_list = list(set(outlet_result['Calendar Year/Week']))
```

I am getting a list with 4 values
['38.2013', '37.2013', 'Calendar Year/Week', '39.2013']

Why is the string (header) included in the list? Please help me understand this concept.

I am using Python 2.7.... has it got something to do with it?

Comment: does this `Calendar Year/Week` or  `Calendar year/Week` affect the results ? not the same; notice **year** and **Year**

Comment: No, I just made a mistake while writing the question. But it turns out there's a problem with the excel file. The values for week was coming as Strings. I fixed it and now it works!